# When to use private methods in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class, but every method in it should be private (apart form `__init__` and `__str__`). Should I denote every method with a double underscore, or is that deemed bad practice?

Comment: I hear that anything in Python is public, and you should organize yourself, when to use them. I'm not really into the advanced part of the OO, but this is what's left in my mind about that.

Comment: Just FYI, name mangling is designed to avoid collisions with commonly used names, not for privacy.

Comment: To precise @detly 's answer: not "commonly used names", but names used in subclasses. "Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables To avoid collision with a builtin name one uses a trailing underscore (list_).

Answer (score 19):

True private methods - those that can't be seen or used from outside of a class - do not exist in Python. What we have are conventions that are merely suggestions to not touch things you shouldn't.

The closest you get to privacy is name mangling. An attribute of MyClass named `__some_attr` will just be renamed to `_MyClass__some_attr` internally, making it slightly awkward to reference it from outside the class.  This is seldom used.  What most people do is simply prefix a single underscore (`_attr`) as a notation that something should not be relied upon & is not part of the public interface.

Using double underscores before and after the identifier, while not prohibited, is considered reserved for internal language details (like 'magic' methods).  You shouldn't go around coming up with new `__attr__`s (unless you're hacking on the interpreter).

Comment: These guidelines are documented in [Pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Comment: What about cases where `__some_attr` will not be referenced at all outside the class? Wouldn't it be fine to use double leading underscore?

Comment: @user5061 - technically a correct use but frowned on.  It makes introspection more difficult.